# Is Buffy the Vampire Slayer the first teen feminist hero of US TV?

Tags: buffy-the-vampire-slayer

Buffy is an action hero that made all the difficult choices, broke up with men that did not love, felt the pain of Angel leaving her but then dealt with this also, found a choice and stood up to it, in regards to the Spike issue. Also, Buffy choose to slay everyone that made an attempt to destroy her life or the lives of the people she loved. Is she the first feminist icon of modern american TV?

Comment: In my understanding "Feminism" is about gender equality (e.g. vote to right, equal pay, ...), but you seem to define it more through display of "strength" (mentally and physically). So maybe you can clarify what you mean by "feminist hero".

Comment: Buffy was a tool of an ancient patriarchal system, Willow was the feminist hero.

Comment: The title of your question asks if Buffy is "the first *teen* feminist *hero* of US TV", but the body asks whether she's "the first feminist *icon* of *modern* US TV". I agree with @Oliver_C, you should edit this to clarify exactly what you're asking.

Comment: *Also, Buffy chose to slay everyone that made an attempt to destroy her life or the lives of the people she loved.*  Cough, cough, Spike.  Nitpicks aside, though, I'm not sure that vengeance is (or *should be*) a qualifier of being considered a "feminist hero."  Or any kind of hero, really.

Comment: @Separatrix: but Buffy freed herself from that patriarchal system, no?

Comment: @Taladris, It's been a long time since I've seen it, but Buffy was freed from the system by dying, it was Willow's power that freed all the rest from the system.

Comment: @Separatrix: I was thinking about Buffy going against the will of the Council. And later, when she released the power of the Slayer into all Potentials (literally empowering women). I will not deny that Willow is a feminist hero too.

Comment: @Taladris, it was Willow who gave the power to all the potentials, Buffy just rounded up some likely ones and put them in harms way. The details of the rest escapes me after all these years.

Comment: @Separatrix: you are right, but if I remember correctly, it was Buffy's idea/decision in both cases. Willow assisted her technically. Between Simone de Beauvoir and the editor that made her work possible, the former is the one that got credited as a feminist. Again, if I am denying anything in Willow's own feminist fight.

Answer (score 5):

**No.**

Buffy debuted in 1996, [*My So Called Life*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0108872) debuted in 1994.  You may also consider [*Blossom*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0101050), which debuted in 1990 and even [*The Patty Duke Show*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0056778), which dates back to 1965, as examples of teenage girls being feminist heroes.